# Integer values stored in varchar fields, give different results while ordering

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by, ascii, max

I have a situation in which I have a column name c_id which is in varchar but contains integer or null values.
(I cannot change the datatype since it is been used like this, from very long, in my project)

My problem is whenever I try to order by my table with that column, it shows me corrupted results and even when I search for the max value it doesn't give me the max value according to its magnitude.

I wonder if it is stored in ASCII form internally, but i m not very sure. 
PLease help me knowing this why this is occurring.

Thanks.

Comment: Still, would you like to change the column to integer datatype?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use [CAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) function:

```
SELECT CAST(c_id AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) id, field1, field2 
FROM your_table
ORDER BY id
```

or

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN c_id IS NULL THEN 0;
        ELSE CAST(c_id AS UNSIGNED INTEGER);
    END AS id
    , field1, field2 
FROM your_table
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Marco, `END CASE;` is used **inside a stored procedure** not inside a query, in the query it's just END with no `;`  I know it's next to impossible to google the correct page for `mysql case`, but this is standard SQL, if you google `CASE ANSI SQL` you should get the correct info.

Comment: @Johan: you've just explained my mistake and already edited my code... what should I tell you? Thanks a lot, really!!! :)

Comment: I would use `NULL` for `NULL` :)

Comment: @SalmanA: I don't know what user wants to do (onestly, using a VARCHAR for an ID is a big problem); your suggestion could be correct... if OP says he needs id to be NULL I'm going to edit my post as soon as possible. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CAST function. Here is some code to show you an example and the difference it makes in the results returned:

```
mysql> SELECT CAST('19.45' AS DECIMAL(5,2)) as result;

+--------+
| result |
+--------+
| 19.45 |
+--------+

1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```